# Working with TreeMaps (21.9- Intro to Java, Liang, 10th Edition)

Tags: java, debugging, treemap

I'm supposed to write a program that returns the capital of a given state in the U.S. using TreeMaps. However, the program returns null when I run it, before I even get a chance to input anything. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

```
public class Map {

  private TreeMap<String, String> pairs;

  public Map() {
    pairs = new TreeMap<String, String>();
  }

  public void readFrom(String fileName) {
    Scanner input = null;
    try {
        input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    while (input.hasNext(" , ")) {
        pairs.put(input.next(), input.next());
    }
  }

  public String get(String key) {
    return pairs.get(key);
  }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map USA = new Map();
    USA.readFrom("states_and_capitals.txt");

    System.out.print("Enter a state: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(USA.get(input.toString()));
}
```

The text file that the program reads from, "states_and_capitals.txt", is formatted such that on each line there's a state and its capital, separated by a comma (no spaces), like so:

Alabama,Montgomery

Alaska,Juneau

Arizona,Phoenix

etc.

Comment: `input.toString()` returns not what you think but string representation of the `input`. You can use `input.nextLine()` instead.

Comment: Should you main method be placed int the class `Map` ?  Also I would rename it to `MyMap` just to not confused with`java.util.Map`

Comment: @mazaneicha Thanks, that's a good point- now I can at least type in an input before it returns null. However, after I type in an input and enter it, it's still returning null.

Comment: @MaxZoom I tried placing the main method into the Map class, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this, I fix the part where you read from text file and populate the TreeMap. I tested and works fine.

```
public class Map {

    private TreeMap<String, String> pairs;

    public Map() {
        pairs = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    }

    public void readFrom(String fileName) {
        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String [] parts = input.nextLine().split(",");
                if (parts.length == 2)
                    pairs.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

    public String get(String key) {
        return pairs.get(key);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map USA = new Map();
        USA.readFrom("states_and_capitals.txt");

        System.out.print("Enter a state: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(USA.get(input.nextLine()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For reading String input using scanner you should use below

```
scanner.nextLine();
```

So in your code you should do

```
System.out.print("Enter a state: ");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String stateName=input.nextLine();
System.out.println(USA.get(stateName));
```

Use <kbd>Enter</kbd> after giving input as statename.

Comment: Thanks, I did that, but it's still returning null after I enter the stateName. I think there must be something wrong with some other part of my code.

Comment: @Asker Maybe you map is not populated ...Check if the while loop is working fine...

Comment: I'm not sure if it's working or not- my thinking is that the hasNext will check for more terms, and if it's not at the end of the list it will keep adding more terms to the map. Is this correct?